# Recv Buffer size in linux server

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

What is the maximum recv buffer size on linux server? I'm facing a recv failed whenever the buffer size is greater than ~1300 something.

Comment: Define "failed". What errno are you getting? Is this UDP or TCP?

Comment: 1472 is the max UDP (ipv4) packet payload.

Comment: Post your code.  And read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: errno is - 1. And it's TCP only.

Comment: Can't post the code here. (violation of policy). It's our server application. Same code base compiled on solaris and linux. In solaris, we did not have any issue. But, in Linux unable to recv.

Comment: errno should be a positive value. You want to log errno immediatly after recv failed.

Comment: @JayanthKumar the thing to do in these cases is write a very small (e.g. 10-50 line) stand-alone program that is just functional enough to reproduce the fault, and then post that.  Half the time you'll figure out what the issue is as part of writing the stand-alone program, and the other half the time you'll have something you can (hopefully) post and let other people advise you about.

Answer (score 0):

*TCP* has no theoretical limit to the size of a buffer being passed.

Still, please note that when doing TCP [`recv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/recv.html) might very well return with having received less bytes then it was told.

The function returns the number of bytes *actually* received.

The code then could just loop around `recv()` until all data expected was received.